# Retrieve Selected Value of MagicSelect MultiValue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magicsuggest

I have multiselect element just like StackOverflow does with their tags.  I don't know how to write the jQuery statement that will retrieve the multiple values that were selected.

Here is what I have so far.

```
HTML
<input id="tagSelect" style="width:400px;" type="text"/>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
var tag = $('#tagSelect').val();
```

Here is the plugin that it uses
http://nicolasbize.github.com/magicsuggest/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to retrieve the values with the plugin:

If the combo is included within a classic form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php">
    <div id="ms"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var combo = $('#ms').magicSuggest({
        data: 'a,b,c,d,e',
        name: 'choice'
    });
</script>
```

then the selection will be serialized in the parameter $_POST['choice'].

If you need to retrieve the values through javascript, there is a getValue() method which will return an array of values:

```
ms.getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not appear to work.

When trying to execute  ms.getValue(); the following error message is logged:

TypeError: ms.getValue is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: It works fine with me, i also face the issue but when i move position of code. It start work.